# Providing a external path for appSettings for asp.net not working with IIS

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am working on a asp.net web application and I have kept the appSettings key/value information inside a separate config file name "CommonSettings.config" file placed at "D:/Common" folder instead of web.config file appSettings section. And I have modified the web.config file of the web application by pointing the appSetting section to the path like below :

```
<configuration>
     <appSettings file="D:/Common/CommonSettings.config">
</configuration>
```

This works through the debugger. But it gives me a permission issue error while hosting the application on the IIS 7.
I have tried with providing access to user "IIS_IUSRS" to the CommonSettings.config file, but didn't workout. Can any body suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

Just for testing purposes, add access to the "Everyone" role to that file. If it will help, than you know for sure that that is strictly NTFS issue and you just need to find the right role you need to assign permissions to.
It could be that the IIS working process is running under other role rather than IIS_IUSRS.